Database isn't using the correct index
I have a table that contains several jsonb columns. Here is a simplified version of it
create table if not exists files
(
  id int generated always as identity primary key,
  source text not null,
  name text not null,
  file_metadata jsonb,
  created_at timestamptz not null default now(),
  updated_at timestamptz not null deafult now(),
  deleted_at timestamptz
)

The actual table has 37 columns, 7 of which are jsonb. The file_metadata column contains multiple key-value pairs, some of which I index. Here are a few examples:
create index parent_file_id_idx on files ((file_metadata->>'parent_file_id')) where deleted_at is null;
create index is_attachment_idx on files ((file_metadata->>'is_attachment')) where deleted_at is null;
create index root_file_id_idx on files ((file_metadata->>'root_file_id')) where deleted_at is null;
create index type_idx on files ((file_metadata->>'type')) where deleted_at is null;

In total, there are actually 10 indexes on different properties in this column. Often times queries involving these conditions of these indices don't work as they should. For example, take the following query:
SELECT files.id, files.name
FROM files
WHERE (file_metadata ->> 'root_file_id') =
      'WOfjfdsk23849EOk'
  AND deleted_at IS NULL;

According to our CloudWatch metrics, this and similar queries are taking an unreasonably long time to execute. I used EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON, ANALYSE) on the query, and found that it's using the is_attachment_idx and not the root_file_id_idx. Other times, it uses the type_idx. So far I've never actually seen the right index (root_file_id_idx) being used. I'm stumped as to why this is happening. The table has around 6.5 million rows. Here's an output from the explain analyse query:
Gather  (cost=1000.43..382305.25 rows=16894 width=38) (actual time=1165.725..1165.916 rows=1 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Index Scan using is_attachment_idx on files  (cost=0.43..379615.85 rows=7039 width=38) (actual time=1157.126..1157.142 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: ((file_metadata ->> 'root_file_id'::text) = 'WOfjfdsk23849EOk'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1115468
Planning Time: 0.250 ms
Execution Time: 1165.942 ms

Does anyone have any insight as to why the wrong index is being used and how to make sure the correct one is used in the future? I'm running a database cluster on rds. My postgres version is:
PostgreSQL 15.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 9.5.0, 64-bit

EDIT
I just checked, and this index is being used for queries that don't filter on the column at all, which makes even less sense to me.
EDIT 2 Following is the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS):
Gather  (cost=1000.43..399893.53 rows=17559 width=39) (actual time=1204.088..1330.039 rows=2 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=631821
  ->  Parallel Index Scan using is_attachment_idx on files  (cost=0.43..397137.63 rows=7316 width=39) (actual time=1278.721..1319.677 rows=1 loops=3)
        Filter: ((file_metadata ->> 'root_file_id'::text) = 'WOfjfdsk23849EOk'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1160849
        Buffers: shared hit=631821
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '10474984kB', maintenance_io_concurrency = '1', search_path = 'public'"
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 0.262 ms
Execution Time: 1330.064 ms


How does a 6.5M row table get reduced to 1 row by filtering 1115468 x3 rows out?  Was the parallel work distributed very unevenly?

Your execution plan looks like the estimates are quite off. Try fixing them with
ANALYZE files;

Note that PostgreSQL will collect statistics for the indexed expressions, which should improve the estimates dramatically. But CREATE INDEX doesn't trigger statistics collection, so you need an explicit ANALYZE after creating an index on an expression (indexes on the column itself are not affected, as PostgreSQL always collects column statistics).
An additional oddity is that PostgreSQL doesn't use a sequential scan. Perhaps you twiddled the optimizer parameters like enable_seqscan. If an ANALYZE is not enough to fix the problem, please add the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for the query to the question.

Thanks for the reply. I tried running ANALYZE files, but that didn't solve the issue. I've added the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) as an edit to the original question.

That is plain weird, because the estimates are still off. It looks as if you didn't ANALYZE. Unlikely, but perhaps extended statistics make a difference: CREATE STATISTICS teststat ON (file_metadata ->> 'root_file_id'), (deleted_at IS NULL) FROM files;. Then another ANALYZE on the table.
